# SonataMediaBundle Не загружается изображение на сервер

Tags: symfony2, sonata

Добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста. Сайт написан с помощью Symfony2. Использую SonataMediaBundle. 
Хочу загрузить изображение. Захожу на "/admin/dashboard", выбираю "Добавить новый медиа-файл", происходит переход на страницу:
/admin/sonata/media/media/create
Затем выбираю "Изображение" (image)
/admin/sonata/media/media/create?context=default&category=3&hide_context=0&provider=sonata.media.provider.image
Выбираю Файл, директория Default, затем "Создать и редактировать".
Локально, на компьютере всё отрабатывает корректно: добавляется медиа-файл, с которым дальше можно работать.
Но на сервере, при нажатии на "Создать" вылетает 500 ошибка:
500 Internal Server Error

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Возможно, у меня что-то не так с настройками. Конфиг такой:

sonata_media:
    db_driver: doctrine_orm 
    default_context: default 
    contexts:
        default: 
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

```
        formats:
            preview:   { width: 100, quality: 100}
            small: { width: 190 , quality: 100}
            big:   { width: 300 , quality: 100}

    news:
        providers:
             - sonata.media.provider.youtube
             - sonata.media.provider.image

        formats:
             small: { width: 190 , quality: 95}
             big:   { width: 300 , quality: 90}

cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
        create:     false
```

sonata_media:
    providers:
        image:
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.square

Comment: Неправильный путь к директории? Нет прав? Приложите error.log Apache/Nginx и PHP.

Comment: Вот, что выдаётся в логах: [2016-07-31 23:25:20] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The directory "/home/host1493957/fonkost.ru/htdocs/web/uploads/media" does not exist." at /home/host1493957/fonkost.ru/htdocs/vendor/knplabs/gaufrette/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/Local.php line 245 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The directory \"/home/host1493957/fonkost.ru/htdocs/web/uploads/media\" does not exist. at /home/host1493957/fonkost.ru/htdocs/vendor/knplabs/gaufrette/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/Local.php:245)"}

Comment: Я понял, в чём проблема. При переносе данных на сервер я директорию web переименовал в www (так требовал хостинг провайдер). На сервере директории web нет, вот и вылетает ошибка. Видимо, в конфигах нужно подняться в родительскую папку и оттуда пойти в www

Comment: Да, как только указал: path: /../www/uploads/media ошибка ушла. неправильная директория была. Сейчас ещё раз внимательно просмотрю все конфигурационные файлы, чтобы больше на это не натыкаться.